# Composer PSR-4 Autoload class not found

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I have been beating my head for a couple hours trying to figure out why the autoload is not working for "Authentication\auth()". The "dBase\db()" class is loading just fine, but i'm getting:

> Error: Class 'Authentication\auth' not found in
>   /var/htdocs/dev/test.php on line 8

when calling test.php.

[image: file_structure]

Root composer.json -

```
  "require": {
    "geeshoe/dbClass": "dev-develop",
    "geeshoe/authClass": "dev-master"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "dBase\\": "vendor/geeshoe/dbclass/",
      "Authentication\\": "vendor/geeshoe/authClass/"
    }
  }
```

authClass.php header -

```
<?php
namespace Authentication;

use dBase\db;

class auth extends db
{
```

test.php -

```
if (file_exists("vendor/autoload.php")) {
    require "vendor/autoload.php";
} else {
    echo "Dam.. Something went wrong!";
}
$test = new \dBase\db();
$var = new \Authentication\auth();
```

If someone could point out the obvious to me, that would be great. On a side note, autoload is not specified in the authClass->composer.json file for testing purposes.

Comment: 1. Anything in `vendor/` is created/controlled by composer and should have its own autoloading config defined already. Don't add entries for them in `composer.json`. 2. Do not create or modify anything inside `vendor/`, only composer itself should ever touch this folder and anything in it. Your code should live somewhere *else* in the project folder, eg: `src/` or `lib/`.

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you for the information. Both of these classes are in development and not production ready, hence not having autoload configured in their respective composer.json files..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that in fact you don't use PSR-4. In PSR-4 class name should match file name. For `db` class its fine because db class is located in `db.php` file, but `auth` class is located in `authClass.php` file and that's the problem. You should update file name to `auth.php`

You might need to run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Also keep in mind in real packages, one vendor package has one namespace, so you don't create multiple namespaces for single package but only single

Comment: Nabialek Thank you, that is what I was looking for. I keep going along the mindset that PSR-4 autoload is binding by the namespace rather than class name and file name..

Comment: "In PSR-4 class name should match class name" <-typo class name should match file name.

Comment: @Jaxchief Thanks, fixed. Glad I could help